# Hide now button only on one instance of timepicker

Tags: jquery, hide, timepicker

I use two instance of timepicker on my page. Is there a way to hide current button in one and not the other. I added the `$('.ui-datepicker-current' ).css('display','none');` to click function but that hides it initially but when I select the date it puts the Now button back.
Tried with `beforeShow`, and `onSelect` also but it does not permanently take the Now button off.

Is there a way I can selectively add a css entry to hide it from a specific instance of timepicker?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes. Try the following CSS:

```
#start .ui-datepicker-current {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: @user3242836 If you are trying to show us some code, please [create a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), and post a link to **your** JSFiddle.

Comment: have 2 timepickers (start, end) loaded inside jquery ready. The initialization of timepicker is                       $('#start').datetimepicker({
                controlType: 'select',
                timeFormat: 'H:mm',
                closeText: 'OK',
                onClose: function(date, obj) {
                            .
                },                                                       $('#start').click( function () {
          $('.ui-datepicker-current' ).css('display','none');
        });
This is earlr...when I tried out yours commented click fn and added suggested to css fil

Comment: @user3242836 Try the latest changes.

Comment: It does not somehow recognize the #start id. I verified many times..not sure what is wrong. If I change it to just the class in the css it disables the current button on both, but unable to select a specific one. Is there any other way such as through an event other than onSelect, something like onFocus...

Comment: I fixed this by disabling the button using css for both my instances and enabling it on event focus on whichever one needed to be enabled.